# is it good idea to remember html tags in css classes and Ids?

Tags: css, xhtml, semantic-markup

If we keep tag name within selectors.

For example:

```
#divMainContentBody { … }

.spanImportant { … }
```

This minimizes the need to switch between your stylesheet and your markup, since the ID and class already tells you what element type it is referring to.

---

**Updated after @Guffa's answer:**

[image]

I found this advise in [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596522315/) also http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/647-how-to-write-efficient-css-selectors/

> Don’t qualify ID selectors
>
> ```
> Because there is only one element in the page with a given ID, there’s
> ```
>
> no need to add additional qualifiers.
>   For example, DIV #toc is unnecessary
>   and should be simplified to #toc.
>
> Don’t qualify class selectors
>
> ```
> Instead of qualifying class selectors for specific tags, extend
> ```
>
> the class name to be specific to the
>   use case. For example, change LI
>   .chapter to .li-chapter, or better
>   yet, .list-chapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefixing identifiers in this was is called [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), and is used for aspects of identifiers that is considered crucial for their use.

In most cases I don't think that the element type is important enough to make it into the identifiers in the CSS. If the names are chosen well you should already be able to determine the important information from them.

If the element is important, you could use it in the selector instead of putting it in the identifier. That way the selector will actually only work with that element:

```
div#MainContentBody { ... }

span.Important { ... }
```

Comment: +1 completely agree.. and it keeps the semantic information the OP wants to maintain in the CSS file..

Comment: This is a minor detail, but span.Important and .spanImportant aren't the same: those rules have different weight, so if you want to override them you have to take that into account, and also the performance of the browser is different because in one case it searches for all elements with one class, and in the first one it then has to verify what's the node name. These are just minor details, but the first one can cause some unexpected consequences due to that little change.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: The advice in the book is sound from a performance perspective, but it does compromise away some other aspects, so you have to decide what you think is more important. The slight differences in functionality that AlfonsoML pointed out applies also to the suggestions from the book.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, this may not be the best practice as using location-dependent styles or "trending" your CSS towards a location-based pattern (i.e. "this can only be used for a span", "this is only for a div") force you to create a 1:1 relationship between your HTML elements and your CSS classes.

CSS classes are appropriately-named since - just like in OO programming - you can have your CSS classes inherit from each other.  To this end your better approach is to keep to a meaningful naming convention (as you've already suggested), but write classes that are modular and can be extended.

The upshot of this is that you can then use one class in a large variety of different ways and places without having to continually override behaviours in your style sheets.  This keeps your styles more predictable and your CSS much more maintainable.

Read more about it on http://wiki.github.com/stubbornella/oocss or [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css).